Local supabase instance does not connect to remote instance even though I had connected it before
In my next js project, I have a local instance of supabase which is connected to a remote db in my supabase db account. I had already connected the local to my remote using the command:
npx supabase link --project-ref <my-project-id>
I also did some pulling and pushing of migration files. That was about a month ago. But now when i do npx supabase db push or npx supabase db pulli get the error:


npx supabase db push
Connecting to remote database...
failed to connect to postgres: failed to connect to `host=aws-0-ap-south-1.pooler.supabase.com user=postgres.<my-project-id> database=postgres`: failed to receive message (timeout: context deadline exceeded)
Try rerunning the command with --debug to troubleshoot the error.

I also get this error when i try relink my local db to remote db.
My remote project on supabase is up and running. I have no VPN enabled. i can't seem to understand why there is  a ** timeout: context deadline** exceeded error
I had encountered this issue two months ago. At the time my VPN was enabled so it caused a timeout: context deadline exceeded. But now there is no such thing in my opinion which can cause this. There seems to be no issue for this particular error on github
